# cshtml c# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, compiler-errors

Im making PostHelper.cshtml in App_Code folder inside my Blog project. And I got this error on line:

```
<div class="commentsTab">
            <a href="@Href("~/Posts/Details/" + **Post.ID + "#comments")">@Post.comments.Count**</a>
</div>
```

and:

```
@foreach (tag Tag in **Post.tags**)
```

when Im deleting "@Post.comments.Count" its fine but Ive got similar line and there's no errors:

```
<div class="postTitle"><a href="@Href("~/Posts/Details/" + Post.ID)">@Post.Title</a></div>
```

whats wrong with this? There's whole code:

```
@using Blog.Models;
@helper Render(post Post, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, bool isAdmin, bool showComments)
{
<div class="postTitle"><a href="@Href("~/Posts/Details/" + Post.ID)">@Post.Title</a></div>
<div class="postContainer">
    <div class="postTabs">
        <div class="dateTab">
            <div class="month">@Post.DateTime.ToString("MMM").ToUpper()</div>
            <div class="day">@Post.DateTime.ToString("dd")</div>
        </div>
        <div class="commentsTab">
            <a href="@Href("~/Posts/Details/" + Post.ID + "#comments")">@Post.comments.Count</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postContent">
        <div class="postBody">@html.Raw(Post.Body)</div>
        <div class="tagList">
            @foreach (tag Tag in Post.tags)
            {
                <span class="tag"><a href="@Href("~/Posts/Tags/" + Tag.Name)">@Tag.Name</a></span>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="linkList">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
                (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
if (showComments)
{
    <div id="commentContainer">
        <a id="comments"></a>
        @foreach (comment Comment in Post.comments.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime))
        {
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="commentName">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Comment.Email))
                    {
                        <a href="mailto:@Comment.Email">@Comment.Name</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Comment.Name;
                    }
                </div>
                said:
                <div class="commentBody">@html.Raw(html.Encode(Comment.Body).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))</div>
                <div class="commentTime">at @Comment.DateTime.ToString("HH:mm") on @Comment.DateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")</div>
            </div>
        }
        <div id="commentEditor">
            <div id="commentPrompt">Leave a comment!</div>
            <form action="@Href("~/Posts/Comment/" + Post.ID)" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="commentNamePrompt" name="name" /> Name (required)<br />
                <input type="text" id="commentEmailPrompt" name="email" /> Email (optional)<br />
                <textarea id="commentBodyInput" name="body" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" id="commentSubmitInput" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

}

My action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        int pageNumber = id ?? 0;
        IEnumerable<post> posts =
            (from Post in model.posts
            where Post.DateTime < DateTime.Now
            orderby Post.DateTime descending
            select Post).Skip(pageNumber * PostsPerPage).Take(PostsPerPage + 1);
        ViewBag.IsPreviousLinkVisible = pageNumber > 0;
        ViewBag.IsNextLinkVisible = posts.Count() > PostsPerPage;
        ViewBag.PageNumber = pageNumber;
        ViewBag.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;
        return View(posts.Take(PostsPerPage));
    }
```

Comment: If your error is in `.."~/Posts/Details/"..` your error is generated in the `Details()` method - you need to post that one

Comment: its only link so its not generated in details its error in this area "+ Post.ID + "#comments")">@Post.comments.Count" and when i delete @Post.comments.Count all is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your exception is caused by an already open connection to the DB that you are not closing. In your case try to add a .ToList at the end of your initial select:

```
select Post).Skip(pageNumber * PostsPerPage).Take(PostsPerPage + 1).ToList();
```

This will close the reader and copy all results in your memory. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: thanks bro! that helped me a lot :D im new in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You need MARS. Add: `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` to your connection string. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx